# Orleans Private Property Deserialization

Tags: .net, serialization, orleans

I have an orleans project with a stateful grain.

Orleans seems to not deserialize private properties when hydrating the state for the grain.

In the image below UserId gets deserialized but not State.

Is there a way to get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the default GrainStorageSerializer to use **System.Text.Json** which allows properties with private setters to be deserialized when you apply the **JsonInclude** attribute to the property as shown below.

```
public class Order
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public OrderStates State{ get; private set; }
}
```

You can then do the follow setup when configuring your environment. Implement
a version of **IGrainStorageSerializer** that uses **System.Text.Json**. In this case below I created **SystemTextJsonSerializer** which implements the interface.

```
public class SystemTextJsonSerializer : IGrainStorageSerializer
{
    public BinaryData Serialize<T>(T input)
    {
        return new BinaryData(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(input));
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(BinaryData input)
    {
        return input.ToObjectFromJson<T>();
    }
}
```

You can then configure your **GrainStorageSerializer** as below.

```
siloBuilder.Services.AddSerializer(serializerBuilder =>
    {
        serializerBuilder.AddJsonSerializer(isSupported: type => type.Namespace.StartsWith("Example.Domain"));
    });
        
.AddAzureTableGrainStorage(
    name: "OrleansProvider",
    configureOptions: options =>
    {
        options.GrainStorageSerializer = new SystemTextJsonSerializer();
        options.ConfigureTableServiceClient("...");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the grain's state a separate serializable object with public properties and let Orleans inject it as an IPersistentState into your grain's constructor like explained in [Grain persistence on Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/grains/grain-persistence/#get-started) in the *Get started* section.

Keep in mind that you can't use the actual state data in the grain's constructor.
Implement [OnActivateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/orleans.grain.onactivateasync) if you need to do extra housekeeping using state data before the first message gets dispatched to your grain.